# Unexpected error when building appcelerator app in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

My Appcelerator application runs without a problem from titanium on my phone, however when I open the xcodeproj file directly in xcode the app runs but reports that the database file is missing.

My app has a database file which will be opened to create a database.

Why would the app not error when launched from titanium, but does error when launched from xcode?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230242/how-do-i-run-the-xcode-project-generated-by-titanium/35261140#35261140

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for taking the time to add information to this. I applied the settings you suggested in xcode, but still have the same problem. Specifically in app startup the js files are foiund correctly in the app, but when the TiDatabaseProxy tries to install the database, the log reports that the database.sql file is not found. As I said if I run this directly on my iphone from titanium it's fine.

Comment: What is database.sql? Is it SQL code or a sqlite database? You might be best to create a ticket at https://jira.appcelerator.org and attach a test case. Then leave a comment here linking to the ticket and I'll take a peek.